# children not inside parent div

Tags: html, css

To my understanding the buttons contained in the div should stay inside of it. This is the case when I make them display as inline, but then they have no size. When I set display to inline-block they appear at the bottom of the page, but this time with the correct size. This is the first time I am doing something with css, so I understand very little about how everything works.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    transition: right 1s;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
}

#slide-1:target ~ .image-container {
    right: 0%;
}
#slide-1:target ~ .buttons > #button-1 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#slide-2:target ~ .image-container {
    right: 100%;
}
#slide-2:target ~ .buttons > #button-2 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#slide-3:target ~ .image-container {
    right: 200%;
}
#slide-3:target ~ .buttons > #button-3 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.buttons {
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
}

.buttons > a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin: 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>Slideshow</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="slider">
        <span id="slide-1"></span>
        <span id="slide-2"></span>
        <span id="slide-3"></span>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/gandalf.jpeg') }}" class="slide">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/mountains.jpeg') }}" class="slide">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/rivendale.jpeg') }}" class="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a id="button-1" href="#slide-1"></a>
            <a id="button-2" href="#slide-2"></a>
            <a id="button-3" href="#slide-3"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6j0f.png)

[image: button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/837h7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements behave just as normal text. They cannot have a specified width/height, but rather expand horizontally to fit their contents, and vertically to match the font-size of the parent element (unless a font-size is assigned to them). In your snippet you have empty `<a>` elements, so setting them to inline will cause them to shrink to zero width.

Comment: Ok, but inline-block has a width and height and should be located inside the parent div?

Comment: It is indeed located inside the parent div. Use the inspector to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody has the same issue as shown with the screenshots:
make sure you have the height of the image set to 100% otherwise it can go beyond the image-container and screw everything up. Apparently images don't scale themselves to fit inside a div.